# Get the Data of assets-library://asset/asset.MOV

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am accessing the videos of my device **photoLibrary**. Everythig is working great. Now I have a video url, I wants to get the data of video so that I can upload to server via REST API, but failed to get the data of video. Getting following error -
`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “asset.MOV” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=52C33235-2BFE-4FA4-AC8C-5E48DC566847&ext=MOV}`

**ImagePickerController code is as follows -**

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
        {            
         if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {// Get the Image    
          }
        else if let videoURL1 = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? URL
            {
         self.videoURL = videoURL1
            }            
         picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
       {
       picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
```

**My code to get the data is as follows -**

```
            do
            {
         let data = try Data(contentsOf: self.videoURL.absoluteURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
                print(data)
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }

            do
            {
       let data = try Data(contentsOf: self.videoURL.absoluteURL)
             }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
```

Comment: Where is this code? Why don't you use the `videoURL` variable? What is the `videoURL1` variable? Why is your code repeated twice?

Comment: @rmaddy updated my code by mistake added videoURL1. Please help me I am working on it from last 4 hours.

Comment: Where did you get the value for `videoURL`? Is it really hardcoded in your app? You tagged this with `UIImagePickerController`. Perhaps you should show your entire `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` method.

Comment: @rmaddy added the code, can you have a look.

Comment: I am getting videoURL from  imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) need to get the data of videoURL.

Comment: Try using `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.

Comment: @rmaddy it works :) Thank you so much . You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

use "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL" instead of "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"